# Returning more than one result

Tags: python, wiki

I'm using the following code:

```py
def recentchanges(bot=False,rclimit=20):
    """
    @description: Gets the last 20 pages edited on the recent changes and who the user who     edited it
    """
    recent_changes_data = {
        'action':'query',
        'list':'recentchanges',
        'rcprop':'user|title',
        'rclimit':rclimit,
        'format':'json'
    }
    if bot is False:
        recent_changes_data['rcshow'] = '!bot'
    else:
        pass
    data = urllib.urlencode(recent_changes_data)
    response = opener.open('http://runescape.wikia.com/api.php',data)
    content = json.load(response)
    pages = tuple(content['query']['recentchanges'])
    for title in pages:
        return title['title']
```

When I do `recentchanges()` I only get one result. If I print it though, all the pages are printed.
Am I just misunderstanding or is this something relating to python?

Also, opener is:

```
cj = CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once a return statment is reached in a function, that functions execution ends, so the second return does not get executed. In order to return both values you need to pack them in a list or tuple:

```
...
returnList = [title['title'] for title in pages]
return returnList
```

This uses list comprehension to make a list of all the object you want the function to return and then returns it.

Then you can unpackage individual results from the return list:

```
answerList = recentchanges()
for element in answerList:
    print element
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having is that a function ends at the first return line it sees.

So. in the line

```
for title in pages:
    return title['title']
```

It returns only the first value: `pages[0]['title']`.

One way around this is to use a list-comprehension i.e.

```
return [ title['title'] for title in pages ]
```

Another option is to make `recentchanges` a generator and use `yield`.

```
for title in pages:
    yield title['title']
```

Answer (score 0):

`return` ends the function. So the loop only executes once, because you're `return`ing in the loop. Think about it: how would the caller get subsequent values once the first value has been returned? Would they have to call the function again? But that would start it over again. Should Python wait until the loop is complete to return all the values at once? But where would they go and how would Python know to do this?

You might provide a generator here by `yield`ing rather than `return`ing it. You could also just return a generator:

```
return (page['title'] for page in pages)
```

Either way, the caller can then convert it to a list if desired, or iterate over it directly:

```
titles = list(recentchanges())

# or

for title in recentchanges():
    print title
```

Alternatively, you can just return the list of titles:

```
return [page['title'] for page in pages]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you use `return`, your function will end after returning first value.

There are two alternatives;

- you can append the titles to a list and return that, or
- you can use `yield` instead of `return` to turn your function into a [generator](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators).

The latter is probably more pythonic, because you could then us it like this:

```
for title in recentchanges():
   # do something with the title
   pass
```